# Stack space in WebAssembly (& WASI)

Tags: system, webassembly, wasi

I'm writing small programs in WebAssembly text format (`.wat`). I've looked at Wasm code compiled from C and it looks like the common practice is to maintain a global stack pointer, and when we enter a function, to create a stack frame by subtracting the stack pointer by some multiple of 4 (e.g. 16):

```
    (global.set $g0
      (local.tee $l1
        (i32.sub
          (global.get $g0)
          (i32.const 16))))

;; --snip--

  (global $g0 (mut i32) (i32.const 67088))
```

I need to implement a very basic `malloc` to do dynamic memory management. In this implementation, I think I need to grow the memory with `memory.grow` if I run out of memory.

My question:

What should I do with the stack space when I grow the memory? AFAIK if I don't do anything the memory looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+  high memory
| Newly acquired memory |
|                       |
+-----------------------+
| Stack space           |
+-----------------------+
| Heap (managed with    |
|       malloc)         |
+-----------------------+  low memory
```

Comment: If you are writing an application directly in WebAssembly, is there any reason why you need to create your own stack? WebAssembly has its own [call stack](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/exec/runtime.html#stack) - allowing you to call functions, maintain local variable state etc ...

Comment: @ColinE The WASM stack isn't addressable, which is why c code compiled to WASM maintains its own "shadow stack"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wasm-ld (the llvm linker for WebAssembly) lays out memory by default with the stack first (at a lower address).   This allows for sbrk (or indeed your custom malloc) to use memory.grow to extent the heap region.   The location of the start of the heap can be found by taking the address of the linker-created symbols `__heap_base`.